# How can I get the contents of an attachment in a Mozilla Thunderbird extension?

Tags: thunderbird

I'm building an extension to Mozilla Thunderbird that does some translation of messages.  I'd like to add a translate attachment feature, although I'm having a bit of trouble getting to the contents of each attachment.  At the moment, I'm hooking into the `attachmentListContext` popup, and I have some code that gathers the relevant attachment URI and URLs.  How can access the binary data of each relevant attachment?

Current code to get selected attachments:

```
handleAttachmentTranslate : function() {
  // see code in msgHeaderViewOverlay.js in Thunderbird source
  var attachmentList = document.getElementById('attachmentList');
  var selectedAttachments = new Array();
  for (var i in attachmentList.selectedItems) {
    var attachment = attachmentList.selectedItems[i].attachment; 
    // we can now access attachment.url or attachment.uri, etc
    selectedAttachments.push(attachment.url);
    // or (ideally)
    // alert(this.translate(getData(attachment.url)))
    // but what is getData()?
  }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FiltaQuilla addon does have the ability to save attachments etc. It may contain some code that's relevant.

Update Apr 25 2011: The [page posted by speedball2001](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Thunderbird/HowTos/Common_Thunderbird_Use_Cases/View_Message) has been modified between Mar 25 and Mar 31. Now it has a complete example. Check that out. It also points to [a real extension](http://blog.xulforum.org/index.php?post/2011/03/14/Basic-MimeMessage-demo) that does exactly the attachment manipulation. This looks to be a promising answer.

The thought now is to hook up this new demo code to FiltaQuilla if necessary.

Comment: Ok. I looked at FiltaQuilla code, it does not extract attachments thus it is not relevant.

Comment: The page pointed to by speedball2001 indicates an idea but there is no sample code. After looking at the references for `nsIIOService.newChannelFromURI()`, `nsIChannel.asyncOpen()`, `nsIStreamListener`, it looks something similar to `nsIMsgMessageService.streamMessage()` is needed to drive the accumulation of content. See the sample under `streamMessage()`. However it is not clear how exactly the code can be.

Comment: Update Apr 25: The page posted by speedball2001 now has a complete example, and a link to a real demo.

Answer (score -2):

Have you checked MDN? They have howtos for this kind of stuff:

http://mdn.beonex.com/en/Extensions/Thunderbird/HowTos/Common_Thunderbird_Use_Cases/View_Message.html